# Windows phone market place error. Failing 5.1.4

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have submitted a windows phone app of PNR status.It failed and error in report says this:

`The application cannot be tested for compliance for Windows Phone Application Certification Requirements due to geographic, hardware, and/or software limitation(s).Please provide valid test PNR numbers with resubmission`

- What should be done for resubmission?
- Only PNR numbers should be sent or any other thing to be done?

Comment: Firstly, please explain what 'PNR' is, as it's pretty hard to answer the question without knowing. The testers need any information or login/account required to fully use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific section at .xap submission page, where you can add data for testers, like logins, passwords, etc. The message in your report shows, that testers need additional data to test your app properly (so you don't need to replace your xap file). When you'll add this info, submit app once again.

Also note, that if your app failed submission, there's a button for contacting market tech support, so you can always ask them, what was wrong, if you're not sure.

You can read about different tech.certification requirements here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> 5.1.4 – App testability    The app must be testable when it is submitted to Windows Phone Store. If it is not possible to test your app for any
>   reason, including, but not limited to, the items below, your app may
>   fail this requirement.
>
> If your app requires credentials, you must include them in the Test
>   notes or instructions field when submitting your app on the Windows
>   Phone Dev Center. The credentials must be valid.
>
> Examples of credentials include:
>
> Login credentials. For example, if your app requires a username and
>   password to access part of the app.
>
> Testing credentials. For example, if your app allows a user to add to
>   a gift card balance, you must include both login credentials and a
>   gift card number that can be tested.
>
> If your app accesses a web service, the web service must be functional
>   and your app must run properly.
>
> If your app interacts with third-party hardware, for example a media
>   streaming device, you must file a technical exception. For more
>   information on how to file a technical exception, see the Technical
>   Exception Request form.
>
> Your app must not require that it is run on a single, specific
>   cellular network.
>
> Your app must launch.

Comment: Can I know , how tech support can be availed?

Comment: If your app submission failed, you'll find it at dashboard->yourApp->lifecycle. You've downloaded your report from this tab, the tech support button is also there. (I hope, I remember it right...)